# getting url value in input box

Tags: php, javascript

In my html page, i have links like this

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="ApplicationRegister.php?plan=trial"><img src="images/box4.png" width="230" height="300" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="ApplicationRegister.php?plan=plan1"><img src="images/box1.png" width="230" height="300" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="ApplicationRegister.php?plan=plan2"><img src="images/box2.png" width="230" height="300" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="ApplicationRegister.php?plan=plan3"><img src="images/box3.png" width="230" height="300" /></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

When i click on any one of the image, it will go to ApplicationRegister.php page with plan= corresponding values.

In my ApplicationRegister.php i have a registration form

```
<form action="emailconfirmation.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1"  onsubmit="return Validate();">
    Company Name: 
        <input type="text" name="CompanyName" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Company E-mail : 
    <input type="text" name="Companyemail" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
     Company Contact <input type="text" name="CompanyContact" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
     Company Address: <input type="text" name="CompanyAddress" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1"/> 
     <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" />
                    </form>
```

In this page it should take the value from url like plan=trail or plan1... whatever there in the url. then while submitting all the values should be submitted along with these form data.

How to achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to sanitize the plan input:

```
<?php
    $plan = @$_GET['plan'];
    $plan = +$plan; #convert to number
?>
```

Just add another hidden field containing that value

```
<form action="emailconfirmation.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return Validate();">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<?php echo $plan ?>"/> 
</form>
```

Another option would be to add it as a get parameter to the `action`:

```
<form action="emailconfirmation.php?plan=<?php echo $plan ?>"
      method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return Validate();">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Downvoted, as in addition to this, you would need to make sure that the value in "plan" is an allowed value (e.g. one of plan1 thru' 4), and then escape it with `htmlspecialchars()` to mitigate against XSS

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are sending a value as a part of the URL then you should have a container to grab it..use the php $_GET[] to grab that value..a bit of googling about php forms will help you rather than giving you the code.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp Read from this link and keep coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hidden field to your form on ApplicationRegister.php that includes the 'plan' query parameter. The following HTML should sit within the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['plan']) ? $_GET['plan'] : 'trial'; ?>" />
```

The code sets the default value to be 'trial', should they visit this page without gone via the previous page.

Then you can handle the form data as you usual in 'emailconfirmation.php'. You can do something like:

```
 if (isset($_POST)) 
 { 
     $post_Plan = isset($_POST['plan']) ? $_POST['plan'] : null; 
     // etc ...
 } else {
     // redirect back 
 }
```